# How to automatically delete photos after google plus upload?

Tags: applications, tasker, images, google-plus, uploads

Once **Google plus** uploads the images, then it automatically delete the image files on the phone for more storage space. Is it possible? Can it be used with tasker or any other app?

Answer (score 0):

**Tasker**  does not support **HTML** response like when photo is uploaded, that's why you can't use it.

But App called **FolderSync** - (paid version) to pack up my photos to cloud. You can set automatic delete of the local files, after transferring them. But with this you can't use **Google+** 's automatic upload.